# How to assess whether a set of cells all have a specified value in Excel

Tags: excel

I have collected a bunch of statistical results in the form of "YES" and "NO" strings.

Now I would like to have a summary cell displaying "YES" if all these cells equal "YES" (or are empty).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you settle for a "TRUE" instead of a "YES" in case there are no "NO" cells?  If so, in a nearby cell type

`=countif([first cell in range]:[last cell in range],"NO")`

Then in an adjoining cell type

`=and([previous cell]="0")`

As an example, if you had YES or NO strings in A1 through A20, then in A22 you would type

`=countif(a1:a20,"NO")`

and in A21 you would type
`=and(a22="0")`

Comment: You could combine these into `=if(countif(a1:a20,"NO")=0,"YES","NO")`

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but THANKS. I ended up using `=IF(COUNTIF(B5:B17, "<>Yes"), "No", "Yes")`